# Resizing views dynamically osx

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have two views and a button at the top, i want one be hidden/shown when the button is pressed and for the other views to resize to the edge of the window.

The button on the top left links to an IBAction that hides the lower view with this `mainscroll.hidden = true`. I can not figure out how to resize/move the other views so the textbox/button are at the bottom of the window, ie no visible gray space at the bottom. I would like to do this programmatically.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuUsa.jpg
[image]

Comment: You probably want to use AutoLayout constraints. Check out this link for an introduction to Auto Layout.: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: This is dangerously close to "here are my requirements, please implement them for me." In situations where you don't know how to do something, spin off a small prototype. Try to accomplish your goal by examining objects (NSobjects? I dunno, your moonspeak is so weird) at runtime. Browse your object graphs via intellisense to look for possible candidates. And research helps as well. If you are unsuccessful, you at least have an SSCCE you can construct a question from, and that others can use to construct their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can adjust the topView programmatically:

```
float aHeight = [mainscroll frame].size.height;
NSRect aRect = [topView frame];
aRect.size.height += aHeight;
aRect.origin.y -= aHeight;
[topView setFrame:aRect];
```